# Fanuc Roboguide and ROS MoveIt

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I want to make a simulation of fanuc robot in `Roboguide`.
This post is bit naive. I want to make sure that I do not miss any configuration steps.
I ask two simple questions here.

This post has two purposes.

- Firstly, to confirm if I follow correctly.
- Second question, at the end of this post.

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS bionic` and  `ros-melodic`.
Basically, I have **ROS/Moveit** respositories for fanuc. I downloaded, installed and built these repositories from [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver) under my `catkin_ws`.

So far, I create a simple motion planning to a pose goal within **rviz / MoveIt** using `move_group_interface`.
My goal is to see the same motion on the Roboguide.

I am following  [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) to install and configure Roboguide on a windows PC.
I have already installed Roboguide. The above link lists the following prerequisites.

- a copy of the fanuc_driver package,
  version 0.2 or newer [I have it on my
  ubuntu system under my `catkin_ws`]
- an installation of Fanuc Roboguide [I
  have it on my windows PC]
- a Windows
  PC or VM (as Roboguide does  not run
  on Linux)

Next, On the above link, under section 4.2 Importing, it says.
In the Cell Browser, import the KAREL and TPE sources into the workcell. Browse to your **local** `fanuc_driver` package. Since, Roboguide is on a windows PC, and  `fanuc_driver` is installed under catkin_ws in ubuntu system. It cannot be local. Do, I have to copy such files manually?

thanks,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356294/fanuc-roboguide-and-ros-moveit/) by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Next, On the above link, under section 4.2 Importing, it says.
> In the Cell Browser, import the KAREL and TPE sources into the workcell. Browse to your **local** `fanuc_driver` package. Since, Roboguide is on a windows PC, and  `fanuc_driver` is installed under catkin_ws in ubuntu system. It cannot be local.

"local" in this sentence means as compared to the remote `.git` repository which is hosted on Github.

> Do, I have to copy such files manually?

That, or `git clone` the repository on your Windows PC too.

It's not too complex all actually: just make sure you have access to the files on the PC you need them. So copy the `karel` and `tpe` directories from `fanuc_driver` to your Windows PC. Keep the rest on your Linux machine.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-02**:
Related comment: you may want to actually use [fanuc_driver_exp](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp).

Still not perfect, but a bit better than `fanuc_driver`.

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2020-07-02**:
thanks a lot @gvdhoorn. I will post any further questions, as I make progress.

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2020-07-06**:
@gvdhoorn, I have edited my original post to add some further information and ask another question? Is this the correct way, or should I put a new question. Thanks,

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-07**:\

> Is this the correct way, or should I put a new question

You should post a new question.

Please revert your edit to remove the new question.